# Python: Sort 2-tuple sometimes according to first and sometimes according to second element

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, max

I have a list of tuples of integers `[(2,10), [...] (4,11),(3,9)]`.
Tuples are added to the list as well as deleted from the list regularly. It will contain up to ~5000 Elements.

In my code I need to use this list sometimes sorted according to the first and sometimes to the second tuple-element. Hence ordering of the list will change drastically. Resorting might take place at any time.

Pythons tinsort is only fast when list are already sorted heavily. So this general approach of frequent resorting might be inefficient. A better approach would be to use two naturally sorted data-structures like the [SortedList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html). But here I would need two lists (one for the first tuple element, and one for the second) as well as a dictionary to create the mapping of the above tuples.

What is the pythonic way to solve this?

---

In Java I would do it like this:

```
TreeSet<Integer> leftTupleEntry = new Treeset<Integer>();
TreeSet<Integer> rightTupleEntry = new Treeset<Integer>();
Hashmap<Integer, Integer> tupleMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>()
```

And have both sorting strategies in the best runtime complexity class as well as the necessary connection between both numbers.

---

- When I need to sort it according to first tuple I need to access the whole list (as i need to calculate a cumulative sum, and other operations)
- When I need to sort according to second element, I'm only interested in the smallest elements, which then is usually followed by the deletion of these respective tuples.
- Typically after any insertation a new sort according to the first element is requested.

---

Comment: What is the access / to modification ratio? If you access it way more often than you modify it, it may be a good idea to use a NumPy array with two different views for the sorting that you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
first_element_list = sorted([i[0] for i in list_tuple])
second_element_list = sorted([i[1] for i in list_tuple])
```

Comment: frequently resorting is a thing which I do not want to do.

Comment: i think you can use a heapq module here

Comment: Yes, that would reduce the complexity of inserting to O(log(n)) but frequently resorting would still be necessary which takes O(n*log(n)) time. I would like to use two seperate heaps (one for each sorting) and whose elements are linked together through a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What I did:

I use the [SortedKeyList](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html#sortedcontainers.SortedKeyList) and sorted according to the first tuple element. Inserting into this list is O(log(n)). Reading from it is O(log(n)) too.

```
from operator import itemgetter
from sortedcontainers import SortedKeyList

self.list = SortedKeyList(key=itemgetter(0))
self.list.add((1,4))
self.list.add((2,6))
```

When I need the `argmin` according to the second tuple element I used

```
np.argmin(self.list, axis=0)[0]
```

Which is O(n). Not optimal.